# Unlocking Meta Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, meta

What is the best way to get more points and unlock more features within the stackoverflow community?

Comment: Look at the help center and see for yourself.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges

Comment: _'what is the next big thing'_ There aren't any "big things" to achieve at Stack Overflow/Stack Exchange, aside reputation points, additional privileges or badges. You should try to achieve "big things" off-line, here it's all _virtual_.

Comment: As you've edited your question a bit, to become clearer, IMHO the answer boils down, to what's stated in these articles: [`How do I write a good answer?`](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) and [`How do I ask a good question?`](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Participation on Meta Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/participate-in-meta) is your first awarded privilege in a series that you gain access to as your reputation and experience on the site grow.

You now have the ability to participate on Meta because you have gained at least 5 rep on the main site.

However, you may want to read [What's Meta?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta) to better understand what Meta is used for.

See [the privileges page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges) in the [Help Center](//stackoverflow.com/help) for the full list.